# R - keep summation column from a tibble for a table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tibble

I am new to R. So far I have managed to find solutions for my problems and adapt my code. However, I have not been able to solve the following problem for 2 days. Probably, there is a very easy solution, but my skills are too limited. Sorry in advance (also for my English).

I try to order numerical values from one column only in accordance to specific value ranges.
The ultimate goal is to have a table in a Rmarkdown file, which list the summations of those values in their representative ranges.

So far, I have only managed to create a tibble with a summation column. Unfortunately, I stuck there. I can not transfer/keep the summation column, even when I transformed the int- into a dbl-column. Knitting the file still only shows the labels (Level 1, Level 2, ...) in a non-summarized fashion. This also happens when I try to print it. The summations would disappear.

tl;dr: How can I keep this summation column, in order to use it in a table in Rmarkdown?

Thanks for any advice!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)


a <-  c(12.3, 13.8, 14.5, 15.4, 16.5, 12.7, 14.2, 16.1, 13.9, 18)
a

## [1] 12.3 13.8 14.5 15.4 16.5 12.7 14.2 16.1 13.9 18.0

b <- cut(a, c(-Inf, '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', Inf), labels=c('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4', 'Level 5', 'Level 6', 'Level 7'))

table(b)

## b
## Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 Level 5 Level 6 Level 7 
##       0       2       2       2       1       2       1

class(b)

## [1] "factor"

b <- as.data.frame(b)

b %>% 
group_by(b, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(Numbers = n()) %>%       
mutate(Numbers = rowSums(.[-1]))

## `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

## # A tibble: 7 x 2
##   b       Numbers
##   <fct>     <dbl>
## 1 Level 1       0
## 2 Level 2       2
## 3 Level 3       2
## 4 Level 4       2
## 5 Level 5       1
## 6 Level 6       2
## 7 Level 7       1

class(b)

## [1] "data.frame"

print(as_tibble(b))

## # A tibble: 10 x 1
##    b      
##    <fct>  
##  1 Level 2
##  2 Level 3
##  3 Level 4
##  4 Level 5
##  5 Level 6
##  6 Level 2
##  7 Level 4
##  8 Level 6
##  9 Level 3
## 10 Level 7

kable(b)

b

Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5
Level 6
Level 2
Level 4
Level 6
Level 3
Level 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to save your updated b object :)

```
b <- as.data.frame(b)

b <- b %>% 
group_by(b, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(Numbers = n()) %>%       
mutate(Numbers = rowSums(.[-1]))
```

Or you could just pipe from the first line like so:

```
b <- as.data.frame(b) %>% 
group_by(b, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(Numbers = n()) %>%       
mutate(Numbers = rowSums(.[-1]))
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I knew it should be easy. Thanks so much!

Comment: @tsch No problem! Happens to the best of us.